# Destroy React Native Component On Blur

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have following navigation structure

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    AppSplashScreen: AppSplashScreen,
    WalkthroughScreen: WalkthroughScreen,
    LoginScreen: LoginScreen,
    BottomTabNavigator: BottomTabNavigator
}, {
    headerMode: 'none',
    cardStyle: { backgroundColor: '#000000' },
});
```

And here is my first screen. I am using a video to display splash screen animation

```
export default class AppSplashScreen extends Component {

    state = {
        displayVideoPlayer: true,
        firstLaunch: false
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        SplashScreen.hide();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.setState({
            displayVideoPlayer: false
        });
    }

    isFirstLaunch() {
        let firstLaunch = true;
        if (true === storage.get('APP_ALREADY_LAUNCHED')) {
            firstLaunch = false;
        } else {
            storage.set('APP_ALREADY_LAUNCHED', true);
            firstLaunch = true;
        }
        return firstLaunch;
    }

    didCompleteVideoPlayback() {
        if (true === this.state.displayVideoPlayer) {
            this.setState({
                displayVideoPlayer: false
            });
        }
        const currentRouteName = this.props.navigation.state.routeName;
        if ('AppSplashScreen' !== currentRouteName) {
            return false;
        }
        if (true === global.SKIP_SPLASH_SCREEN_REDIRECT) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.isFirstLaunch()) {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('LanguageScreen');
            return false;
        }
        this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#000000', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                {true === this.state.displayVideoPlayer &&
                    <Video
                        source={VIDEO_SPLASH_2}
                        muted={true}
                        repeat={false}
                        playInBackground={false}
                        resizeMode="contain"
                        onEnd={() => this.didCompleteVideoPlayback()}
                        style={{height: '100%', width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#000000'}}
                    />
                }
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

My issue is, whenever I open the application it triggers `didCompleteVideoPlayback` and try and execute the redirect which conflicts with other app level redirect such as, redirect on click of push notification, or navigation state persistence etc.

How do I make sure that if `AppSplashScreen` is not in focus, it must not display the video and not trigger `didCompleteVideoPlayback`

PS: `componentWillUnmount` is not destroying Video component from the memory, I want to make sure that

Any pointer in here is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be working with navigation listener, here is what I did

```
componentDidMount() {
    SplashScreen.hide();
    this.focusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
        this.setState({
            isFocussed: true
        })
    });
    this.blurListener = this.props.navigation.addListener('didBlur', () => {
        this.setState({
            isFocussed: false
        })
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.unsubscribeListeners();
    }, 100);
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#000000', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            {true === this.state.isFocussed &&
                <Video
                    source={VIDEO_SPLASH_2}
                    muted={true}
                    repeat={false}
                    playInBackground={false}
                    resizeMode="contain"
                    onEnd={() => this.didCompleteVideoPlayback()}
                    style={{height: '100%', width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#000000'}}
                />
            }
        </View>
    );
}
```

I am not sure if this is the good way of dealing with this stuff or if there is a better way to do this.